# Dropdown menu in plotly.js to switch between charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

I'm trying to create a way to automatically visualise many different types of data on an online dashboard. I'm using plotly.js (built on top of d3) to make these visualisations. For now, next to the default chart, I want to create a drop down box that allows you to switch to other chart types, but I can't get it to work and haven't found examples of something similar done in plotly. Any help would be great!

My code is below which queries the server for the data, and then plots it in a histogram. I can get individual charts to work, just not with the drop down box. I'm not even sure if what I've done by making the drop down object a function is allowed, and if I can use it to change the data to be plotted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simple Bar Chart</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script> </script>
  <style>
    .bar {
      fill: steelblue;
    }
    .bar:hover {
      fill: brown;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart" style="width:90%;height:600px;"></div>
  <!-- For plotly code to bind to -->
  <div id="drop-down"></div>
  <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 80, left: 40 };
    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    // append a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

     // sends asynchronous request to the url
    var HttpClient = function() {
      this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200) {
            aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
          }
        }
        anHttpRequest.open("GET", aUrl, true);
        anHttpRequest.send(null);
      }
    };

    var client = new HttpClient();
    //hard coded URL for now, will accept from UI later
    myURL = "https://neel-dot-village-test.appspot.com/_ah/api/searchApi/v1/fetchChartData?chartSpecs=%7B%22axis1%22%3A+%22name%22%2C+%22axis2%22%3A%22cumulativeNumbers.totalBudget%22%7D&topicType=%2Ftype%2Ftata%2Fproject";    

    client.get(myURL, function(response) {
      var jresp = JSON.parse(response); //get response as JS object
      plotHist(JSON.parse(jresp.json));
    });

    var chooseChart = function(data){
      buttons: [{
          method: plotHist,
          args: data,
          label: 'Histogram'
      }, {
          method: plotBar,
          args: data,
          label: 'Bar Chart'
        }]
    };

    var plotHist = function(data) {
      var plotdata = [{
        x: data.y.values,
        type: 'histogram',
        marker: {
          //color: 'rgba(100,250,100,0.7)'
        },
      }];

      var layout = {
        xaxis: { 
          title: data.y.label,
          rangeslider: {} }, //does not automatically adjust bin sizes though
        yaxis: { title: "Count" },
        updatemenus: chooseChart(data),
        autobinx: true
      };
      Plotly.newPlot('chart', plotdata, layout);
    };

    var plotBar = function(data) { //using plotly (built on d3)
      var plotdata = [{
        x: data.x.values,
        y: data.y.values,
        type: 'bar'
      }];

      var layout = {
        xaxis: { title: data.x.label },
        yaxis: { title: data.y.label },
        updatemenus: chooseChart(data)
      };

      Plotly.newPlot('chart', plotdata, layout);
    };

  </script>
</body>
```